# C# unity if statement logic

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine, logic

I recently started learning to code in C# for Unity; in the following script trying to enable and disable an object (enemy) based on the position of the mouse.

The problem is the code works fine in enabling the object, but I can't figure out how to disable it once it's been activated, so that the object appears and disappears as the mouse moves back and forth - in and out of range. Please let me know if you have a solution. Thank you!

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections;

public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject enemy;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        enemy.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        Vector3 paddlePos = new Vector3(8f, this.transform.position.y, 0f);

        float mousePosInBlocks = Input.mousePosition.x / Screen.width * 16;

        paddlePos.x = Mathf.Clamp(mousePosInBlocks, 6f, 8f);

        this.transform.position = paddlePos;

        if (mousePosInBlocks < 6f)
        {
            print("1");

        }
        else if (mousePosInBlocks <= 6.5f)
        {
            print("2");

            enemy.SetActive(true);


        }
        else if (mousePosInBlocks <= 7.5f)
        {
            print("3");

        }
        else
        {
            print("4");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Start()` method is called automatically when the scene with the object starts. `Update()` is run every frame. You're disabling the enemy when the scene (or object is created) starts and then if mousePosInBlocks is equal or less than 6.5 you activate it. You could do a `Debug.Log(mousePosInBlocks)` if you're unsure about the value of mousePosInBlocks

Answer (score 4):

How are you expecting the object to become disabled when you're never calling `enemy.SetActive(false);`? It's only invoked in your `Start` method but this will be overridden by `enemy.SetActive(true);` which is being called in the `Update` method every frame.

I'm not sure when your object should become disabled but just add `enemy.SetActive(false);` in the respective if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the line of code to disable the object in your update class, since you said it should be disabled when you move the mouse out of range, i'm guessing the line should go in your else statament

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections;

public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject enemy;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        enemy.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        Vector3 paddlePos = new Vector3(8f, this.transform.position.y, 0f);

        float mousePosInBlocks = Input.mousePosition.x / Screen.width * 16;

        paddlePos.x = Mathf.Clamp(mousePosInBlocks, 6f, 8f);

        this.transform.position = paddlePos;

        if (mousePosInBlocks < 6f)
        {
            print("1");

        }
        else if (mousePosInBlocks <= 6.5f)
        {
            print("2");

            enemy.SetActive(true);


        }
        else if (mousePosInBlocks <= 7.5f)
        {
            print("3");

        }
        else
        {
          enemy.SetActive(false);
            print("4");
        }
    }
}
```

In any case you only need to add `enemy.SetActive(false);`inside the if, if-else or else statament, make sure it's inside it, otherwise it will get called during every frame and it will stay disabled